# Investigate $f(x)=\frac{\tanh (x)-1}{e^{-2 x}}$ for $x \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital

The following are given

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{\log(x)} = \infty$$

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{\cosh(x)} = \infty$$

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{\sinh(x)} = \infty$$

$$
\tanh x=\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}=\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}} \quad \text { for } x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{x^2} = \infty$$

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}{\exp(x)} = \infty$$

Both the denominator and the numerator goes to infinity. I do not know how to handle this. A hint or a bit more will be helpful.

Differentiation are not allowed.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is it the limit in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}\frac{\tanh (x)-1}{e^{-2 x}}&=e^{2x}\big(\tanh (x)-1\big)\\&=
e^{2x}\left( \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}-1\right)\\&=
e^{2x}\left(\frac{-2e^{-x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}\right)\\&=
\frac{-2e^{x}}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}\\&=\frac{2}{e^{2x}+1}-2
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$\tanh(x)-1=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}-1=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}-\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{-2e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$

$\implies \frac{\tanh(x)-1}{e^{-2x}}=\frac{-2e^{x}}{e^x+e^{-x}} \to -2$ as $x \to \infty$.